# Is there a way to save the query result from postgres to use in a following query?

Tags: postgresql

I have these queries

```
foouser=# create table a(id int PRIMARY KEY, foo text, bar text);
CREATE TABLE
foouser=# START TRANSACTION;
START TRANSACTION
foouser=*# insert into a values(1, 'foo', 'bar') on conflict (id) DO UPDATE SET foo = excluded.foo where a.bar = 'bar';
INSERT 0 1
foouser=*# insert into a values(1, 'foo', 'bar') on conflict (id) DO UPDATE SET foo = excluded.foo where a.bar = 'bara';
INSERT 0 0
```

we see if the insert query inserts a row the result is `0 1`, if the insert query does not then the result is `0 0`. Is there a way to use those results to decide whether to continue or rollback the transaction? I would like to avoid an unnecessary select query if possible.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76365/188406) or [that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/131825/188406), using `GET DIAGNOSTICS v_cnt = ROW_COUNT` - but usually you'd do that check in your client application, not in pgpsql.

Comment: Why does it matter? You have already done the action by the time you check the result and the `UPSERT` has completed. The `UPSERT` has taken care of doing the right thing so I don't see why a `ROLLBACK` would be necessary.

Comment: If the upsert inserts no rows and updates no rows, I know the system has changed since my last expected state. In the case where no rows have been updated, I know I need to rollback and retry with new information. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Again why? The operation either inserted/updated a row or it did not. If it did not then a rollback is not going to change anything. What you are looking for is branching logic, `if this then that else something else` and pure SQL does not do that. You have a couple of choices 1) Look before you leap and do a select first to see if the conditions changed and then do the insert. 2) Leap and ask forgiveness later, probably using `RETURNING` to capture the id or lack of for the row inserted/updated. In either case this will need to be done in a function on the client or in Postgres.